# Unit test JMS 2.0 using embedded Artemis

Tags: java, junit, jms, activemq-artemis

I try to test an application which consumes JMS messages using JMS 2.0 API.

To reduce the complexity of my test I send a message inside the test using a MessageProducer and try to read it back using a MessageConsumer on the same session.

I use an embedded ActiveMQ-Artemis 2.5.0 instance which is JMS 2.0 compliant.

```
package be.attle;

import javax.jms.CompletionListener;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ActiveMQClient;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ServerLocator;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.ActiveMQJMSClient;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQResource;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class ActiveMQTest {
    @Rule
    public EmbeddedActiveMQResource resource = new EmbeddedActiveMQResource();

    private Queue queue;
    
    private ConnectionFactory factory;
    private Session session;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ServerLocator serverLocator =  ActiveMQClient.createServerLocator("vm://0");
        factory=new ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory(serverLocator);
        queue = ActiveMQJMSClient.createQueue(AsyncJobConst.QUEUE_NAME);
        Connection conn=factory.createConnection();
        session=conn.createSession(false,Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void easyPeasy() throws JMSException
    {
        
        MessageProducer producer=session.createProducer(queue);
        CompletionListener listener=new CompletionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onException(Message message, Exception exception) {
                System.err.println("message send failed:"+exception);
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(Message message) {
                System.out.println("message send successfully");                
            }
        };
        
        producer.send(session.createTextMessage("testBody1"),listener);
        producer.send(session.createTextMessage("testBody2"),listener);
        // (1)
        // let's try the consume the first message
        MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(queue);
        Message message=consumer.receiveNoWait();
        Assert.assertNotNull(message);
    }
}
```

At (1) the console shows twice "message send successfully". However when I try to read from the queue, the assert fails (=no message found). My session is not transacted.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: FWIW, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60676137/consume-message-from-mq is the same essential question.

Comment: I've been looking at pre-existing messages but did not find this one. Thanks. I notice the search bar is less efficient as the search used while entering a new ticket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#start--) on the connection is required to start the connection's delivery of incoming messages. You can find a simple example [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.5.0/examples/features/standard/message-counters/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example/MessageCounterExample.java#L106).